# Show and hide divs with JavaScript and append to URL with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

On the homepage `www.example.com` I have divs `#thumbnail1, #thumbnail2, #thumbnail3`. When one of these divs is clicked, a fullscreen div `#details-wrapper` (hidden by default) displays, thanks to the following JavaScript:

```
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('details-wrapper').style.display = "block"; }
```

In this div `#details-wrapper`, I have other divs `#details1, #details2, #details3` which are all hidden by default.

This is what I need:

1) When a thumbnail div is clicked, the corresponding details div displays and appends its id to the URL in the address bar. (example: `#thumbnail1` is clicked, `#details-wrapper` and `#details1` are displayed and`/details1` is appended to the URL.)

2) Likewise, when navigating to the main page URL followed by a details ID (example: `www.example.com/details1`), `#details-wrapper` and `#details1` are displayed.

3) Only one "details" div is displayed at a time.

4) Clicking a div `#next` (which is inside `#details-wrapper`) displays the next `#details` div.

```js
function showDiv() {
 document.getElementById('portfolio-details').style.display = "block";
}

function hideDiv() {
 document.getElementById('portfolio-details').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#thumbnail1, #thumbnail2, #thumbnail3 {
    float: left;
    background: #000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#portfolio-details {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

#details1, #details2, #details3 {
    display: none;
}

#details1 {
    background: #333;
}

#details2 {
    background: #555;
}

#details3 {
    background: #777;
}

#next, #close {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbnail1" onclick="showDiv()">
</div>
<div id="thumbnail2" onclick="showDiv()">
</div>
<div id="thumbnail3" onclick="showDiv()">
</div>
<div id="portfolio-details">
    <div id="details1">
    </div>
    <div id="details2">
    </div>
    <div id="details3">
    </div>
    <div id="next">
    Next
    </div>
    <div id="close" onclick="hideDiv()">
    Close
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To append into url you need to use pushState. I would suggest you to use history.js (https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/). Hiding & displaying divs is not a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Use this HTML:

```
<div id="thumbnail1" data-id ="thumbnail1" class="thumbnail" >
</div>
<div id="thumbnail2" data-id ="thumbnail2"  class="thumbnail"">
</div>
<div id="thumbnail3"  data-id ="thumbnail3"  class="thumbnail">
</div>
<div id="portfolio-details">
    <div class ='details' id="details1">
        dsadsd1
    </div>
    <div class ='details' id="details2">
        asdsa2
    </div>
    <div class ='details'  id="details3">
        asdsada3
    </div>
    <div id="next">
    Next
    </div>
    <div id="close" >
    Close
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is js:

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('portfolio-details').style.display = "block";
    var text = $(this).data('id');
    var lastChar = text.substr(text.length - 1);    
    $( "#portfolio-details div").removeClass('show-details');
    $( "#portfolio-details div:nth-child("+lastChar+")" ).addClass('show-details');
}

function hideDiv() {
    document.getElementById('portfolio-details').style.display = "none";
}

function next(){
    if($("#portfolio-details .details").last().hasClass("show-details")){
        $("#portfolio-details .details.show-details ").removeClass('show-details');
        $("#portfolio-details .details:first").addClass('show-details');
         /*put your url modification code here*/
    }else{  
        var next_div  = $(".details.show-details ").next('div');
        $("#portfolio-details .details.show-details ").removeClass('show-details');
        next_div.addClass('show-details');
        /*put your url modification code here*/

    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#next').click(next);
    $('.thumbnail').click(showDiv);
    $('#close').click(hideDiv);   
})
```

and add css

```
#thumbnail1, #thumbnail2, #thumbnail3 {
    float: left;
    background: #000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#portfolio-details {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.details {
    display: none;
}

#details1 {
    background: #333;
}

#details2 {
    background: #555;
}

#details3 {
    background: #777;
}

#next, #close {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
}
.show-details{
    display:block !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eqq7bxed/3/

To append `div ids` in `url` you have to follow this [link](http://github.com/browserstate/history.js)) as mentioned in comments under your question

Comment: Thanks, works great. One thing though - this only works if the amount of thumbnails/divs is 9 or less. Do you have a solution to support double digits (10 or more)?

Comment: Nevermind! For var lastChar I replaced `text.substr(text.length - 1);` with `text.match(/\d+$/)[0];` and this returns any numbers in the string instead of the last character of the string.